Indexing into an array of arrays, then iterating over it with a foreach
In the below example, I try to define an array of arrays \bvs, and then I try to iterate over the elements of \bvs[1], i.e. I am hoping to iterate over the list {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1}. However, instead the output shows that \x takes up only one value, that of (1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1) ,(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0) ,(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1)[1].
Note that I would like to access elements of \bvs manually, so I'd like to use \bvs[1] at some points, and \bvs[2] at others, etc., not just using a pair of nested foreachs.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\bvs{(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1)
          ,(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)
          ,(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1)}
  \foreach[count=\c] \x in {\bvs[1]} {
    \node (\c,\c) {\x};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


There are two problems:

The list in \foreach is not evaluated and expanded, so the loop iterates over the single element \bvs[1]. Expand the array access in advance:
\pgfmathsetmacro\bvsi{\bvs[1]}
\foreach[count=\c] \x in \bvsi { ... }


The syntax of the array is wrong. The list needs surrounding braces, and needs to be a list of strings to keep the inner commas (otherwise it is interpreted as a list of lists).
\def\bvs{{"1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1","0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0","0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1"}}




\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\bvs{{"1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1","0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0","0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1"}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\bvsi{\bvs[1]}
  \foreach[count=\c] \x in \bvsi {\node at (\c,\c) {\x};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

In the code above, I have replaced (\c,\c) by at (\c,\c), to place the nodes at different positions. The original version without at assigns the name (\c,\c) to the nodes and places them at the same position, one over the other such that only the last one is visible in the end.

TeX is not black magic. Defining \bvs as (1,0),(0,0) doesn't allow you to call \bvs[1] and hope it returns (1,0). TeX will just present (1,0),(0,0)[1].
Here's a working implementation; the subarrays are separated by semicolons.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definearray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_cactus_array_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_cactus_array_#1_seq } { ; } {#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {c}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\arrayitem}{mm}
 {
  \seq_item:cn { l_cactus_array_#1_seq } {#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definearray{bvs}{
  1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1;
  0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0;
  0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach[expand list,count=\c] \x in { \arrayitem{bvs}{1} }
   {
    \node at (\c,\c) {\x};
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


We can even do more if we allow the second argument of \arrayitem to be empty and, in this case, to return the number of items.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definearray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_cactus_array_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_cactus_array_#1_seq } { ; } {#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {c}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\arrayitem}{mm}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
   {% get the number of items with blank argument
    \seq_count:c { l_cactus_array_#1_seq }
   }
   {% get the item with a nonblank argument
    \seq_item:cn { l_cactus_array_#1_seq } {#2}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definearray{bvs}{
  1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1;
  0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0;
  0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach[expand list,count=\b] \y in { 1,...,\arrayitem{bvs}{} }
   {
    \foreach[expand list,count=\c] \x in { \arrayitem{bvs}{1} }
     {
      \node at (\c+\b,\c) {\x};
     }
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



I think Cactus intends to work with pgf arrays

@gernot I don't think that PGF arrays are workable tools.
